# Else in shell expect command

Tags: php, shell, expect

I have successfully executed the following command via php but it only works straight forward. If the host is already added or any expect is mismatched means it is failing. Can anyone suggest a way to handle this even if the expect is mismatched it should goto the next step?

```
shell_exec("expect -c 'spawn sudo su - root -c \"ssh-copy-id -i " . $host . "\"
            expect \"yes/no\"
            send \"yes\r\"
            expect \"password:\"
            send \"yyyy\r\"
            interact'");
```

Comment: In what manner, you are expecting the expect to handle the fail scenario ?

Comment: You probably want `expect eof` instead of `interact`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `exp_continue` to get this solved.

```
"expect -c 'spawn sudo su - root -c \"ssh-copy-id -i " . $host . "\"
expect {
    \"yes/no\" {send \"yes\r\";exp_continue}
    \"password:\" {send \"yyyy\r\"}
}
interact'"
```

If `Expect` sees `yes/no`, will send `yes`, then it will continue again;
If it sees `password`, will send the password. Afterwards, it will proceed with `interact` command.

Note : As Mr.Glenn pointed out, if you actually need to intact with shell, use `interact`. Since you are executing this from `php`, it is better to go ahead with `expect eof` only.